# Filter DataFrame using within-group expression

Tags: python-polars

Assuming I already have a predicate expression, how do I filter with that predicate, but apply it only within groups? For example, the predicate might be to keep all rows equal to the maximum or within a group. (There could be multiple rows kept in a group if there is a tie.)

With my dplyr experience, I thought that I could just `.groupby` and then `.filter`, but that does not work.

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[0, 0, 1, 1], y=[1, 2, 3, 3]))
expression = pl.col("y") == pl.col("y").max()

df.groupby("x").filter(expression)
# AttributeError: 'GroupBy' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

I then thought I could apply `.over` to the expression, but that does not work either.

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[0, 0, 1, 1], y=[1, 2, 3, 3]))
expression = pl.col("y") == pl.col("y").max()

df.filter(expression.over("x"))
# RuntimeError: Any(ComputeError("this binary expression is not an aggregation:
# [(col(\"y\")) == (col(\"y\").max())]
# pherhaps you should add an aggregation like, '.sum()', '.min()', '.mean()', etc.
# if you really want to collect this binary expression, use `.list()`"))
```

For this particular problem, I can invoke `.over` on the `max`, but I don't know how to apply this to an arbitrary predicate I don't have control over.

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[0, 0, 1, 1], y=[1, 2, 3, 3]))
expression = pl.col("y") == pl.col("y").max().over("x")
df.filter(expression)
# shape: (3, 2)
# ┌─────┬─────┐
# │ x   ┆ y   │
# │ --- ┆ --- │
# │ i64 ┆ i64 │
# ╞═════╪═════╡
# │ 0   ┆ 2   │
# ├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
# │ 1   ┆ 3   │
# ├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
# │ 1   ┆ 3   │
# └─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had updated to `polars>=0.13.0` your second try would have worked. :)

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(dict(
    x=[0, 0, 1, 1], 
    y=[1, 2, 3, 3])
)

df.filter((pl.col("y") == pl.max("y").over("x")))
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Wow, fixed the day before I asked the question... When will I learn to check for updates regardless of how I recently I updated? :-)